# Boot Clonezilla from a ext4 USB

Tags: clonezilla

Is there a way to boot Clonezilla from a ext4 formatted USB? I use such memory for my system backups and would like to also use it to boot Clonezilla

Answer (score -1):

1. Format the memory as *ext4* if needed
2. Install tuxboot on the Ubuntu machine. Instructions here http://tuxboot.org/download/
3. *sudo tuxboot*
4. Proceed to install Clonezilla as usual
5. Machine should boot from the memory

Comment: If you check Clonezilla instructions, it says: _Ensure that your USB flash drive contains at least one FAT or NTFS partition_.